# Prove that this has a normal distribution

Tags: statistics

In my book I read that a  certain denstiy of a random variable $\beta $

$$p(\beta) \propto \exp \left\{-\frac1 2 \beta^TA\beta + \beta^Tb \right\} $$

where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite invertible matrix.

They say that this has a certain normal distribution. But how can one see this? I prefer to see a proof or a link to a proof or something. Thanks!

Comment: Apply the result in your previous question with $\Sigma^{-1}=A$ and $\theta=\Sigma b$.

Comment: Really, this was practically answered in the previous question.

Comment: I know, this is the wrong thread for the bounty..

Comment: I've refunded your bounty.